# Why can't I access my API variable in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I am trying to access a variable that is running using an API GET request.
When I get the result as console output, I get the correct value, but it doesn't work when I want to output the element in my HTML code.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="ml-3">
<p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 group-hover:text-gray-900">{{ test }}
</p>
<p class="text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 group-hover:text-gray-700">View profile</p>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
<script setup>
var userStore = useUsersStore();
var currentUser = await userStore.getById(1);
console.log(currentUser.data.firstName);
const test = currentUser.data.firstName;
</script>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: The use of `await` restricts the comp to be used exclusively with Suspense

Comment: Can you send me an example? @EstusFlask

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#loading-state

Comment: `test` should also be made [reactive](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref) or else it's value in your HTML will always display as it's initial value, which is 'undefined' until your async call to your store is complete